# How to compile my Math Stack Exchange Mathjax into a PDF document?

Tags: amsmath, mathjax, compiling

I have a rather lengthy post on Math SE at the following link.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308162/how-is-the-matrix-of-a-linear-operator-affected-by-a-change-of-bases

Now I'd like to be able to compile the code I've written for this post into a PDF math document for my pupils, most of whom don't have access to the Internet and so are in need of this material in a PDF file to be shared with them through a USB data traveler.

I'm running WinEdit + MikeTex on a Windows 8.1 (64 bit) platform.

However, when I copy the code from the above post into a WinEdit file based on the AMS Article template and try to compile, there are plenty of errors, which necessitate a lot of modification.

Is there a way out with my current software?

Here is what the preamble of my template reads.

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
% Article Class (This is a LaTeX2e document)  ********************
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
% THEOREMS -------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: MathJax seems to promote bad LaTeX practice.

Comment: `pandoc -f markdown -t latex -o test.pdf test.md`

Comment: @HenriMenke I'm sorry but I just didn't get your comment!

Comment: Consider reading this: [How to print out a full q/a entry? Or forward it outside the StackExchange site?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/825/5764)

Answer (score 4):

MathJax promotes bad LaTeX practice. This is a fact, not an opinion.

### MathJax side

1. You should never use `\matrix{...}`, but `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}`. Better, instead of

   ```
   \left[\matrix{...}\right]
   ```

   use

   ```
   \begin{bmatrix}...\end{bmatrix}
   ```
2. Never use `$$\begin{align}...\end{align}$$`; MathJax accepts it without `$$` fore and aft.
3. Never use `\\` inside a `$$...$$` construction, but `\begin{gather}...\end{gather}`
4. `\tag` belongs *in* `align`.

### Conversion to LaTeX

When you want to convert the code to a LaTeX document,

1. change `$$...$$` into `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`
2. change `{align}` into `{align*}`
3. change `{gather}` into `{gather*}`
4. convert Markdown markup into LaTeX; for instance `_words_` into `\emph{words}`

### LaTeX style

You abuse `\left` and `\right`; for instance,

```
\left[x \right]_E
```

should simply by `[x]_E`. Also `B'` is much simpler than `B^\prime`. So

```
$E^\prime = \left( e_1^\prime, \ldots, e_n^\prime \right)$
```

is much better input as

```
$E' = ( e_1', \dots, e_n' )$
```

Note `\dots` and not `\ldots`.

Comment: Great advice but I think OP will not appreciate it.  Most users want it to *Just Work* ™.

Comment: @HenriMenke My MathJax essentially does that. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg thanks. But from your answer, I gather that there is no solution other than editing my Mathjax source to make a lot of modifications.

Comment: @egreg isn't there any software for compiling Mathjax directly into a PDF document?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Use Google Chrome and press `Ctrl+P` to display Print Preview. Select Save as PDF. MathJax is a web technology so you need to use web browser unless you are prepared to do the full conversion manually.